# How to configure supported methods of ResourceHttpRequestHandler?

Tags: java, spring

I'm working with Spring-boot with Spring security enbaled, it automatically creates a [ResourceHttpRequestHandler](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/resource/ResourceHttpRequestHandler.html) that only supports `GET` `HEAD` `OPTIONS` methods by default.

In my case, Spring security will raise `AccessDeniedException` after an unauthenticated `POST` request and will eventually hit `ResourceHttpRequestHandler` from where a friendly reminder of access denied in JSON payload returned.

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
                 .....
                .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/public/access_denied.json");
    }
```

Currently, `ResourceHttpRequestHandler` throws method not allowed for every POST request.

So, I would like to know how to add `POST` to the list of supported methods of `ResourceHttpRequestHandler`.

I've tried the following but not working at all:

```
@Log4j2
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    public WebMvcConfig(ResourceHttpRequestHandler handler) {
        log.error("handler: {}", handler);
        handler.setSupportedMethods(RequestMethod.GET.name(), RequestMethod.HEAD.name(), RequestMethod.OPTIONS.name(), RequestMethod.POST.name());
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In your case, if access is denied, your page is a static resource, thus you get a `ResourceHttpRequestHandler`, as this serves static resources. What do you need to POST?

Comment: @JRK because I am doing a POST request to some protected controller, If I'm authenticated there won't be any problem. Actually my denied page is tailored to work with Ajax.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add **POST** to the list of supported methods of **ResourceHttpRequestHandler**, try this one:

```
@PostConstruct
public void addSupportType() {
    SimpleUrlHandlerMapping handlerMapping = applicationContext.getBean("resourceHandlerMapping", SimpleUrlHandlerMapping.class);
    Map<String, ResourceHttpRequestHandler> urlMap = (Map<String, ResourceHttpRequestHandler>) handlerMapping.getUrlMap();
    for (Map.Entry<String, ResourceHttpRequestHandler> entry : urlMap.entrySet()) {
        entry.getValue().setSupportedMethods("GET", "POST");
    }

}
```

I hope it works for you.

[java](/questions/tagged/java)[springboot](/questions/tagged/springboot)[resourcehttprequesthandler](/questions/tagged/resourcehttprequesthandler)